# What is the correct way to make a SELECT in PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php

How can i do a select from a variable received from a form?

I have the following code but i think that i cannot do this : '%'.$texto.'%'

```
$busqueda=$_POST['texto'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];

if($tipo='titulo')
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LIBRO WHERE LI_TITULO like '%'.$texto.'%'",$conexion);
```

What should i do? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LIBRO WHERE LI_TITULO like '%{$busqueda}%'",$conexion);
```

**Edit:**

You also have bug in your `if` statement:

```
if($tipo='titulo')
```

That's not a comparison, it's an assignment. If you want to compare, use

```
if($tipo==='titulo')
```

Comment: is it ===(three equals)? or (==)two? i think it should be ==(two) equal sign.is'nt it?

Comment: In this case it's the same thing because you can't have anything else than a string to be equal to `'titulo'`. `===` will also check to see if the variables have the same type, while `==` will first convert the operands to a common type before comparing.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, I would strongly advise to never use in production. See the other answers for how it should be done.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: Read the question, it was not about SQL injections or input validation. It's up to Vaul make sure $busqueda is clean.

Comment: @riad: PHP is a weakly typed language. That means a lot of type conversion is happening behind the scenes. For example, ('test' == true) evaluates to true but ('test' === true) does not. Typesafe comparison removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @Saul You have to be clear in your answer about that. Given the source code he provided, `$busqueca` comes from user input and it's not secured at all. Your answer is suggesting that he could use user input data directly in SQL query, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: My answer suggests that the variable name was incorrect and nothing else. See the 1st comment.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, guys, I take care about SQL Injection and I repair the code.

Answer (score 2):

Always do mysql_real_escape_string() on variables or some kind of filtering:

if you expect integer parse the variable

```
$myId = (int)$POST['id'];
```

if you expect string with no HTML:

```
$myString = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($POST['string']));
```

And so on. Never trust user's input!!!

The best option is to use a PHP framework because all frameworks have thought of potential weaknesses and provide reliable architecture and classes/functions for common tasks, e.g. Database, User login, etc.

Some frameworks you can have a look: [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com), [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `if($tipo == 'titulo')`, or you'll always get true there
2. `mysql_real_escape_string` on any user input that you put in your query strings
3. comment your code
4. indent you SQL, even if it's in a PHP string. like so:

   ```
   $res = mysql_query("
       SELECT * 
       FROM `libro` 
       WHERE `li_titulo` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($texto)."%'
   ", $conexion);
   ```
5. uppercase only for keywords and maybe functions. MySQL is case insensitive.

Comment: pls add a ' sign befor and after the % sign. example: WHERE `li_titulo` LIKE ''%'.mysql_real_escape_string($texto).'%''

Comment: Actually the other way around. The SQL string is delimited by `"`. Thanks for the heads up.